# Woo-commerce show products filtered with ACF fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

I have added a **Gender** fields to my woo-commerce products using an ACF checkbox field.
It is simply **[] Male [] Female** checkboxes.

Now I am trying this code to show only the products with **Male** checked. Later I want to try with female checked and then both checked.

```
function show_by_gender( $query ){ 
$args = array(
  array(
    'key'       => 'gender',
    'value'     => array('"Male"') , //put keywords in "" as its serialized in the DB
    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    )
);
$query->set( 'meta_query', $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'show_by_gender' );
```

I am getting an Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in // filepath //

And in product page - all products where acf field is ticked, irrespective of Male or Female is getting shown. It does not show the products where the Gender acf field is empty.

When I used `'compare' => 'IN'` - it doesn't show any products.

Also my database have "gender" and "_gender" both fields - btw I have also tried this earlier with attributes so one of them could the that. Can you tell me what they mean?
What is the difference between `'compare'` and `'operator'`? I used operator when trying this example with tax_query and attributes - it worked perfectly. I am trying to learn so please bear with me. In my database the data looks like this - `a:1:{i:0;s:4:"Male";}` - `a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Female";}` and

`a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Female";i:1;s:4:"Male";}`

Comment: If I comment out the 'value' the result doesn't change.

Comment: Putting "Male" in double inverted comma helped. Solved.
Updating the working code.

Comment: Good work mate.....